# transformar lista nomeada para dataframe

Tags: r, data.frame, tibble

Gostaria de transformar uma lista nomeada para um `data.frame` (ou tibble) em que o nome do objeto na lista se torne uma observação no `data.frame`

O exemplo de lista que tenho é este:

```
mylist <- list(a_palette = c("#2A363B", "#019875", "#99B898", "#FECEA8", 
"#FF847C", "#E84A5F", "#C0392B", "#96281B"), ppalette = c("#F7DC05", 
"#3d98d3", "#EC0B88", "#5e35b1", "#f9791e", "#3dd378", "#c6c6c6", 
"#444444"), bpalette = c("#c62828", "#f44336", "#9c27b0", "#673ab7", 
"#3f51b5", "#2196f3", "#29b6f6", "#006064", "#009688", "#4caf50", 
"#8bc34a", "#ffeb3b", "#ff9800", "#795548", "#9e9e9e", "#607d8b"))
```

Gostaria de obter como resultado dados como este:

```
dt <- tibble(palette = c("a_palette", "ppalette", "bpalette"),
       hex = c('"#2A363B", "#019875", "#99B898", "#FECEA8", 
"#FF847C", "#E84A5F", "#C0392B", "#96281B"', '"#F7DC05", 
"#3d98d3", "#EC0B88", "#5e35b1", "#f9791e", "#3dd378", "#c6c6c6", 
"#444444"', '"#c62828", "#f44336", "#9c27b0", "#673ab7", 
"#3f51b5", "#2196f3", "#29b6f6", "#006064", "#009688", "#4caf50", 
"#8bc34a", "#ffeb3b", "#ff9800", "#795548", "#9e9e9e", "#607d8b"'))
```

`head(dt)`

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  palette   hex                                   
  <chr>     <chr>                                 
1 a_palette "\"#2A363B\", \"#019875\", \"#99B898\~
2 ppalette  "\"#F7DC05\", \n\"#3d98d3\", \"#EC0B8~
3 bpalette  "\"#c62828\", \"#f44336\", \"#9c27b0\~
```

Estava tentando algo com o comando `stack(mylist)`; mas acabei sem encontrar uma saída. Alguém tem teria alguma solução?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como quer os códigos hexa cotados, precisa de um pouco de manipulação de strings:

```
dt <- data.frame(
  palette = names(mylist),
  hex = Reduce(rbind,
               sub("$", "'", sub("^", "'",
                   lapply(mylist, paste, collapse = "', '")))),
  row.names = 1:length(names(mylist))
)
```

Mas se é para armazenar as paletas em um objeto, manter como lista pode ser mais prático.

Comment: Obrigado por comentar. Mas, nessa solução não tenho a coluna "hex".

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se é isso que precisa.

Comment: Obrigado, Carlos, era isso que eu estava tentando. Tem umas operações aí que nem imaginei. Como disse, pode até ser mais fácil trabalhar com listas, mas tenho pouca prática com elas, por isso, para mim, melhor usar data.frame. Valeu!

Comment: data.frame é um caso especial de lista, o acesso de elementos nomeados é igual: `mylist$bpalette` ou `mylist[["bpalette"]]`